# Watin - Handling Confirm Dialogs with ConfirmDialogHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, watin

Using Watin, I'm trying to handle a confirm dialog box and tell watin to press "OK". This is reasoanbly well documented on the internet - you use a `ConfirmDialogHandler` and the `UseDialogOnce` method.. Except it isn't working for me. I get the following error:

`WatiN.Core.Exceptions.WatiNException: Dialog not available within 5 seconds`

I'm using the watin 2.0 beta atm, but I was previously using an earlier version of 1.X which had the same issue. Tested on a colleagues machine running 64 bit Vista, I'm running 64 bit Windows 7.

The code looks like this:

```
        using (IE ie = new IE("http://localhost/TestApp/TestConfirmPage.asp"))
        {
            var approveConfirmDialog = new ConfirmDialogHandler();

            using (new UseDialogOnce(ie.DialogWatcher, approveConfirmDialog))
            {
                ie.Button(Find.ByName("btn")).ClickNoWait();
                approveConfirmDialog.WaitUntilExists(5);
                approveConfirmDialog.OKButton.Click();
            }
            ie.WaitForComplete();
        }
```

The ASP page is very simple, it consists of a button that forces a confirm, like this:

```
<input type="button" name="btn" id="btn" value="Click me" onclick="ConfirmApp()"  />
```

And `ConfirmApp` has been stripped down for testing so that now all it contains is:

```
 bOK = confirm("You clicked a popup. Did you mean to?");
 return bOK;
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626538/watin-ie9-cant-click-ok-buttons/9769242#9769242

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code looks fine to me, and I think it should work. The only think I did differently it was to put Wait for Complete inside using Dialog block. Don't know why but before I did that I also have some issues, sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. And I don't use time limitation at Wait until exists.  But you probably already tried that one.

For example:

```
using (new UseDialogOnce(ie.DialogWatcher, approveConfirmDialog))
        {
            ie.Button(Find.ByName("btn")).ClickNoWait();
            approveConfirmDialog.WaitUntilExists();
            approveConfirmDialog.OKButton.Click();
            ie.WaitForComplete();
        }
```

Comment: Using a combination of code changes like this and a refresh of the DLLs sorted it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and tried many things but just overlooked one part i was calling  .Click() and then just changed it to .ClickNoWait() and things sorted. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and no matter what I do it was not working until I found a workaround which take time but work for me.

The default time to elapse for `WaitUntilExists()` **is 30 secs** so when using it in IE9 provide extended time limit as following.

`handler.WaitUntilExists(40); // or whatever time suits you above 30`

It certainly take time but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just spent a couple of hours with variations on the dialog watcher solution. Nothing worked for me in IE9.

I ended up with a one-liner that works for me, hope it helps somebody else! This approach completely avoids trying to deal with the dialog by using user key presses instead.

- For OK. Do all steps leading up to button ClickNoWait, then:

SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");

- For CANCEL. Do all steps leading up to element ClickNoWait, then: 
  SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
  SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");

nb: using System.Windows.Forms