# Watin & IE9 - Cant click ok buttons

Tags: c#, watin, internet-explorer-9

I'm using Watin to navigate through a large number of different websites, and I'm using the great solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454422/c-watin-add-an-alertdialoghandler-to-click-ok-button-on-every-alert-dialog-win) to automatically click ok on all the javascript and ie boxes that popup.

The problem is, this solution works great for ie6-ie8, but no longer works for IE9.

Does anyone have anyone suggestions on how to get IE9 to auto click/close all prompts?

(I'm using the latest Watin release, and the code below)

```
public class something {

public something() {
IE browser = new IE("about:blank");
addHandlers(browser);
.. do stuff with browser

}

  //Just click ok to everything
        private void addHandlers(Browser browser)
        {
                    browser.AddDialogHandler(new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.AlertAndConfirmDialogHandler());
                browser.AddDialogHandler(new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.AlertDialogHandler());
                browser.AddDialogHandler(new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.CertificateWarningHandler());
                browser.AddDialogHandler(new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.CloseIEDialogHandler(false));
                browser.AddDialogHandler(new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.ConfirmDialogHandler());
                browser.AddDialogHandler(new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.DialogHandlerHelper());
                browser.AddDialogHandler(new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.FileDownloadHandler("me.htm"));
                browser.AddDialogHandler(new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.FileUploadDialogHandler("me.htm"));             
                browser.AddDialogHandler(new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.PrintDialogHandler(WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.PrintDialogHandler.ButtonsEnum.Cancel));
                browser.AddDialogHandler(new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.PromptDialogHandler(false));
                browser.AddDialogHandler(new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.RefreshWarningDialogHandler(false));
                browser.AddDialogHandler(new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.ReturnDialogHandler());
                browser.AddDialogHandler(new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.SecurityAlertDialogHandler());
                browser.AddDialogHandler(new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.SimpleJavaDialogHandler());
                browser.AddDialogHandler(new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.SecurityAlertDialogHandler());
                browser.AddDialogHandler(new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.AlertDialogHandler());
                browser.AddDialogHandler(new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.SimpleJavaDialogHandler());
                browser.AddDialogHandler(new OKDialogHandler());
            }

}


    public class OKDialogHandler : WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.BaseDialogHandler
    {
        public override bool HandleDialog(Window window)
        {
            var button = GetOKButton(window);
            button.Click();   
            return false;
        }

        public override bool CanHandleDialog(Window window)
        {
            return GetOKButton(window) != null;
        }

        private WinButton GetOKButton(Window window)
        {
            var windowButton = new WindowsEnumerator().GetChildWindows(window.Hwnd, w => w.ClassName == "Button" && new WinButton(w.Hwnd).Title == "OK").FirstOrDefault();
            if (windowButton == null)
                return null;
            else
                return new WinButton(windowButton.Hwnd);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for cleaning the code up david, i had issues trying to format it

Comment: I use WatiN heavily and am waiting to upgrade to IE9 before support is stable...I recommend you downgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WatiN 2.1 has recently been released which addresses a number of [IE9 issues](http://watin.org/documentation/release-2-1-0-1196/). You can download it from http://watin.org/ or update using NuGet:

> PM> update-package watin

Comment: Thanks Jim, watin 2.1 seems to be capable of clicking this ie9 dialogs and seems a bit faster to boot!

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue and no matter what I do it was not working until I found a workaround which take time but work for me.

The default time to elapse for **`WaitUntilExists()`** is 30 secs so when using it in IE9 provide extended time limit as following.

```
handler.WaitUntilExists(40); // or whatever time suits you above 30
```

It certainly take time but it works.