# WatiN ie9 confirm dialog is not working

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-9, watin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Watin & IE9 - Cant click ok buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626538/watin-ie9-cant-click-ok-buttons)

```
var dialogHandler = new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.ConfirmDialogHandler();
            using (new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.UseDialogOnce(browser.DialogWatcher, dialogHandler))
            {
                browser.Button(Find.ById("btnSave")).ClickNoWait();

                dialogHandler.WaitUntilExists();                                       
            }
```

it's not working on ie 9, javascript confirm
I already use latest version 2.1

Answer (score 0):

```
ConfirmDialogHandler confirmHandler = new ConfirmDialogHandler();
        using (new UseDialogOnce(browser.DialogWatcher, confirmHandler))
        {
            confirmHandler.WaitUntilExists();

            confirmHandler.CancelButton.Click();
        }
```

it works on ie7, but not on ie 9
DrunkenMonkey's answer is not working

WatiN-2.1.0.1196

Comment: ok it is sometimes works, sometimes not....

Answer (score 0):

If Your confirm dialog doesn't work in IE9, try next decision

(Visual studio 2010, Windows7, NetFramework 4.0, Internet explorer 9)

First you must add refernce UIAutomationClient and UIAutomationTypes to your test project.

The next method extends Browser class

```
public static void ConfirmDialogIE9(this Browser browser)
    {
        browser.ShowWindow(NativeMethods.WindowShowStyle.ShowMaximized);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        System.Windows.Automation.TreeWalker trw = new System.Windows.Automation.TreeWalker(System.Windows.Automation.Condition.TrueCondition);
        System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement mainWindow = trw.GetParent(System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.FromHandle(browser.hWnd));
        System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElementCollection main = mainWindow.FindAll(System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope.Children
       , System.Windows.Automation.Condition.TrueCondition);


        foreach (System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement element in main)
        {
            if (element.Current.Name.Equals("VIIS - Windows Internet Explorer") && element.Current.LocalizedControlType == "pane")
            {

                System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement DialogBox = trw.GetFirstChild(element);

                DialogBox.SetFocus();
                System.Windows.Automation.InvokePattern clickOk = (System.Windows.Automation.InvokePattern)
                DialogBox.FindAll(System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope.Children, System.Windows.Automation.Condition.TrueCondition)[0].GetCurrentPattern(System.Windows.Automation.AutomationPattern.LookupById(10000));
                clickOk.Invoke();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                break;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the following code in my project:

```
var cancel = browser.Link(Find.ByUrl(CANCEL_LINK));
var confirmDialog = new ConfirmDialogHandler();
using (new UseDialogOnce(browser.DialogWatcher, confirmDialog))
{
    cancel.ClickNoWait();
    confirmDialog.WaitUntilExists();
    confirmDialog.OKButton.Click();
    browser.WaitForComplete();
}
```

This works in IE9. Note that it is WatiN v2.0.50727, but I don't see that this should make a difference with you running v2.1.

Comment: What should the CANCEL_LINK be? Thanks!

Comment: @buzzzzjay: `CANCEL_LINK` is `String` variable holding the URL of the link to find. Look at the intellisense from `Find.ByUrl`, and you'll see that there are different versions to use, depending on what you want to use when mapping the link.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to get this to work with IE9? I keep getting a WatiNException was unhanded because it times out after 30 seconds.

Answer (score -2):

Watin has methods to handle dialogs. Try using this methods:

```
public static void SetCloseIEHandler(bool clickOk)
{
    closeIeHandler = new CloseIEDialogHandler(clickOk);
    BaseIEController.IE.DialogWatcher.Add(closeIeHandler);
}

private static void ClearDialogHandler(IDialogHandler dialogHandler)
{
    if (BaseIEController.IE.DialogWatcher.Contains(dialogHandler))
    {
        BaseIEController.IE.DialogWatcher.Remove(dialogHandler);
        dialogHandler = null;
    }
}
```